# Get raster expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, arctoolbox

In Arcmap I have made a new raster with ArcToolBox -> Spatial Analyst Tools -> Map Algebra -> raster calculator.

Now, months later, I have forgotten the source formula expression.

How can I display?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the original output of this process and you actually ran it from a geo-processing tool then why not have a look at the metadata (ESRI call metadata Item Description) of this dataset? It will contain a [log](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002100000035000000) of this tools execution which includes the inputs, one of which will be the raster expression it was built from.

If you did not run it this way or did further processing of the data that wiped the metadata then you are pretty much out of luck. But there is a lesson to be learned here! If you are the source of the dataset why are you not documenting how you created it (in the metadata)? You've just demonstrated *to the World* that you'll not be able to to replicate your processing\analysis. Would you want to employ someone who could not explain how they constructed their dataset?

So you should always add some description to your metadata about what you did, it can often be just a few lines to yourself and adding that type of information is really helpful as no one remembers what they did 6 months ago...

Answer (score 1):

How long ago ? There is a way tha you can look back, if possible, is to go to ArcGIS  Geoprocessing menu and then you scroll down to Results. Check to see if you have that result of what you did save in that .

[image]

If you want to keep these results, open Geoprocessing Options and go to Results Management and change to whenever you want. There is a list to choose from 2 weeks to never delete,

I hope this helps.